# In NextJS is it possible to serve .docx files in production build?

Tags: next.js, docx, serve

I've read the documentation that you can only serve static files from the public folder, like pictures, fonts or stylesheets.

I placed my .docx file in the public folder, and in developer build it works fine, it downloads the file, but as soon as I run the production build, the .docx can't be found in the build and can't be downloaded, it says "unknown server error".

If I'm wrong and the .docx (which is by the way static) can't be served if I place it in the public folder and run the production build, then how / where should I place the .docx to be downloadable in production build?